# To display data on Pie Chart in silverlight using WCF Ria Services

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, charts, ria

I am trying to display data from database on Pie chart and Area Series chart in my application using WCF Ria services. I followed this link to achieve the same : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Getting-Started-WCF-RIA-1469cbe2

When I am displaying the data in datagrid it is working fine but in case of chart the same logic is not working. This is the code in xaml I am using :

```
`<riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="True" Name="ErrorTrackingDataSource" QueryName="GetErrorTrackings" LoadSize="10">                             
<riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
<ds:BSADomainContext></ds:BSADomainContext>
</riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
<riaControls:DomainDataSource.SortDescriptors>
<riaControls:SortDescriptor PropertyPath="PID" Direction="Ascending"></riaControls:SortDescriptor>
</riaControls:DomainDataSource.SortDescriptors>
</riaControls:DomainDataSource>

<toolkit:Chart Title="Incident Count - Weekly" BorderThickness="2"  Name="acChart" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ErrorTrackingDataSource, Path=Data}">

<toolkit:Chart.Axes>
<toolkit:DateTimeAxis x:Name="XAxis2" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=TimeofCreation,          Path=Data}">
</toolkit:DateTimeAxis>
<toolkit:LinearAxis x:Name="YAxis2" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Incident, Path=Data}"></toolkit:LinearAxis>
</toolkit:Chart.Axes>

<toolkit:Chart.Series>
<toolkit:AreaSeries Name="errorTrackingAreaSeries" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ErrorTrackingDataSource, Path=Data}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding ElementName=XAxis1}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding ElementName=YAxis1}" 
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ErrorTrackingDataSource, Path=Data}">
</toolkit:AreaSeries>
</toolkit:Chart.Series>
</toolkit:Chart>
```

`
I don't know what approach to follow?

Comment: Your `IndependentValueBinding` and `DependentValueBinding` are incorrect. You should rather write `DependentValueBinding="{Binding SalesProfit}"`, i.e. a property of the item or a column from the database instead of your current bindings.

Comment: Thanks!!!! But I tried that also with no success....still I am getting error.

Comment: Edit your post, what code exactly you tried and what error it throws. I think the error message will have all information what is wrong.